# New Zealand uniform or elsewhere?

Tags: identification, world-war-one, uniform, new-zealand

I am trying to identify the man in this photo and thought I'd start with the uniform. The photo was among New Zealand photos, but I don't see the NZ on his badge.
I'd be grateful for any information.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWEX3.jpg]

Answer (score 9):

Uniform is definitely New Zealand Army, you can see the southern cross on the buttons.
The badges represent the New Zealand Army Service Corps and the curved badges on the epaulettes will have the letters NZASC.

The uniform is from WWI and includes a 1903 pattern bandolier which was standard issue to various Imperial forces at the time. The slouch hat has a white stripe on khaki pugaree representing the ASC in accordance with the regulations of 1912 and presumably the white piping on the epaulettes do the same.

This could be a photo from the start of the war as the uniforms were simplified after the Gallipoli campaign and piping on epaulettes disappears.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.